# Why google maps freeze on my Joomla website

Tags: google-maps, plugins, joomla, freeze

I developed website under Joomla 3.5.1. and I have problem with Google maps on my website. When I go on my contact page where Google Maps by Reumer plugin is installed (version 3.4) maps loads and it freeze so I can't zoom, change map type, move map or anything else. Sometimes I can do few actions and it again freeze.

Link to the page with map is: http://studiomob.rs/index.php/en/contact

Where could be the problem?

Comment: JavaScript console is showing "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."

Comment: Yes, I noticed this, but have no clue what I should do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin is causing the problem. I suggest you to replace map by simple iframe code from google maps. Don't forget to disable WYSIWYG editor.

Full solution: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/how-tos/content-management/how-to-embed-a-google-map-into-a-joomla-page/

Comment: Well, that's the final solution if I don't find reason why this is happening. I used this plugin so many times and didn't have any problems, but this is making me crazy :)

Comment: I tried everything, but there was no cure. It definitely has something with this plugin. I found another plugin BT Google Maps and it will solve my problem. Tnx for your effort guys :)